# В статье "Что такое Мета и как она работает?" в справке дублируется заголовок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

> [image: пикча]

Comment: А кто такая Мета, и где она живет? А вдруг она не курит, а вдруг она не пьёт...

Comment: @älёxölüt скорее, не просыхает.

Comment: Или не проветривается :) еще заметил что нормы доступны и через нормы, и через бинайс. Багу писать лень.

Comment: @älёxölüt вот так всё и приходит в упадок =/

Comment: это не наш упадок, это их упадок! Во всём виноват %username%

Comment: @älёxölüt вижу руку Кремля.